# Wordpress custom dropdown listings

Tags: customization, menus, dropdown

I have a site with a database of repair shops, by; 
Manufacturer - Venue

I want 2 dropdown lists at the home page.

In the first dropdown, when i select the "Apple" the second list appears in the places where they are "Apple" repair shops, and when i press the "Submit" button, it redirects me to its page.

Like;
When i select in the first dropdown "Apple"
It lists: 
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
-6
-7

When i select "7" and press "SUBMIT" redirect to: mysite.com/7.

How can i do it?:l

Answer (score 1):

Populate your data something like this and and you can use Javascript/jQuery to achieve this.

```
<select class='apple_store_location'>
<option value='1' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/1"> Place 1</option>
<option value='2' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/2"> Place 2</option>
<option value='3' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/3"> Place 3</option>
<option value='4' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/4"> Place 4</option>
<option value='5' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/5"> Place 5</option>
<option value='6' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/6"> Place 6</option>
<option value='7' data-url="http://mysiteurl.com/7"> Place 7</option>
</select>

<script>
//Using jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.apple_store_location').change(takeMe2URL);
    function takeMe2URL() {
       var new_url =  $('option',this).data('url');
       window.location.replace(new_url);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: This probably can be built dynamicly depending on where meta data is provided.

Comment: Of course. It will be build dynamically. But the jQuery/Javascript thing work on front end and has the above look.